# Pro/Con of reusing single CommandObject instance between multiple forms/actions?

Tags: grails, spring-webflow, grails-controller

Are there any disadvantages to using a single instance of a grails command object across multiple actions?

I.E. you have a several pages with forms in a process and thus create a single grails command object class and only use a single instance of the class throughout the process.

Presume the instance is stored in the flow of a webflow, thus accessible throughout the process, and when validate is called it's provided with a list of properties to validate instead of validating all the properties.  The command object properties are populated like obj.property1 = params.property1 not with bindData() or as a parameter.

Is this a good fit for a grails command object or should a command object for each form be created?

Edit:
I guess what I'm looking for is a Pro/Con list of using one command object for one entire process with multiple forms vs. multiple command objects.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use single CommandObject for each form and only reuse the CommandObject in multiple forms if the forms are for same purpose but in different pages.